# Setting focus on an input based on a template reference

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 / angular 2 application, where I have a number of buttons on a view that display and hide small form fields.

My goal is to set focus on the form fields when I click the appropriate button.

I'm trying to use template variables to do this, but it's not working.

Here is what the input field looks like:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="businessData.company" placeholder="Company" #jobInput>
```

And the button looks like this:

```
    <button class="plus" ion-button clear icon-left (click)="showJob = !showJob; jobInput.focus()">
      <ion-icon name="md-add-circle"></ion-icon>
      add job
    </button>
```

So since this is not working. It's obviously wrong.   :-)

Any help would be appreciated.

By the way, it would be a bonus if anyone also knows how to place the field into view when the fields appear. Some of them appear below the keyboard.

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems to work when I try it in a StackBlitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dspwn6?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: When you say it's not working, do you mean in iOS, in Android, or in both?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use elementRef.focus().

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ztqjjv